# how to update str object recieved from wtforms?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

i need to do some manipulation with string which i get from WTForm, here is my code:

```
from app import app
from app.forms import InputTextForm, OutputTextForm
from flask import render_template, request
import re

def work_txt(text):
    textlookfor = '[0-9]+\n\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+ --> \d+:\d+:\d+,\d+'
    result = re.sub(textlookfor, '', text)
    return result

@app.route('/elmucon', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def elmucon():
    form = InputTextForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        t = request.form.to_dict()
        text = t['text']
        result = work_txt(text)
        return render_template('elmucon_ready.html', form=form, text=result)
```

function work_txt() works fine outside the route, but with my code i recieve the same string which was inputted in Form. What sould i do to make this work? thanks!

Comment: You might include your `work_txt()` function source code in the question.

Comment: @kindall ok done